# Is There a Way to Change Windows 10 PIN Programmatically?

Tags: windows-10, script, automation, password-management

So I was hoping to make a script that would change Windows 10 PIN dynamically such that when logging in it would change to increase security. I won't disclose what my script would do exactly, but for example, let's say the PIN is 0000, then next time it would be 0001, then 0002, etc. I found the process that is responsible for handling the PIN change, CredentialUIBroker.exe. However, I don't know if there is a file that keeps the PIN stored somewhere unencrypted. After using Resource Monitor to analyze the files being accessed by CrednetialUIBroker.exe, all seemed to be encrypted or just temporary cache files.

I would really like to do this project, and after lots of Googling I was unable to go any further in attempting to change the PIN programmatically. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you want to increase the security of your pin increase its length and complexity. The idea of a pin is that it is simple to use and secures your network from a stolen password. If the pin is compromised it only compromises the one system. [Why is a pin better than a password?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-why-pin-is-better-than-password). Being it is backed by security hardware (TPM) it’s highly unlikely the TPM nor the OS is going to allow you to tamper with it. In other words, there’s no use for what you want.

Comment: @Appleoddity I realize a longer length and complexity will add security. If you managed to change the PIN dynamically, it would increase complexity without having to add length. I figured that the file was most likely too secure to handle, however. It would've been cool to do a project like that though! Thanks for the insight